# Preg_match_all time catch multiple PHP

Tags: php, regex

The formats I'm looking to catch using `preg_match_all()`:

- 12.00
- 10:00
- 10am
- 13pm
- 8pm
- 7am
- 1830
- 2.15pm
- 9.45am

The regex I have so far:

```
/((\d{1,2}|\d{4})(.\d{1,2}))(am|pm)*/i
```

Any help much appreciated, I can't seem to catch 5 & 6 with current regex.

Comment: is this true `1830` ?

Comment: The preg_match_all is used against a freetext field where the end user writes many variations of time for multiple pieces of content. I use the regex to populate a newly added time value to a date field. '1830 (uk time)' is present in multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\b(\d{1,2})([.:]?\d{1,2})?([ap]m)?\b/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI1rU8/1)

Breakup of the regex:

```
\b       # word boundary
\d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits for hours
[.:]?    # match *optional* dot or colon i.e. minute separator
\d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits for minutes
([ap]m)? # match *optional* am/pm
\b       # word boundary
```

Comment: Well of cores there are sooo many regex questions if there are only code answers, with no explanations. Because they never understand it and only copy&paste it, so for every regex they have to ask a new question. (But I don't have to tell you that, since I did this already tones of times!)

Comment: @anubhava Can you please explain this regex

Comment: I've added some explanation of regex in my answer.

Comment: Does it always needs 2 people for asking you to explain your code/what you changed?

Comment: No sir there is no rule like that. I am at work and in between coding bringing focus on SO. Besides I always had regex101 demo link in answer with a detailed explanation in it.

Comment: @anubhava Maybe your are interested in this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274 (quoted:) *Code-only answers fall under "Very Low Quality" for me and are candidates for deletion*.* (quote end) <- And with 44 upV's I don't think I'm alone here.

Comment: Yes I know that link and as I wrote earlier this answer was never **code only**.

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to make a discussion here. (You just have to "hope" that the regex101 server is never down, never changes their links and their host, otherwise your link is *ZAPP* and gone)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^(\d{1,2})([.:]?\d{1,2})?(am|pm)?$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                   : regex delimiter
  ^                 : begining of string
    (               : capture group 1
      \d{1,2}       : one or two digit
    )               : end group 1
    (               : capture group 2
      [.:]?         : optional . or :
      \d{1,2}       : one or two digit
    ),              : end group 2 otional
    (am|pm)?        : am or pm optional
  $                 : end of string
/i                  : regex delimiter with caseinsensitive flag
```

Comment: How about a good explanation? It seems like you know enough to give OP a good explanation, so that he understands your regex and maybe even be able to write the next regex by himself!